# Random array gives invalid output after first element [C]

Tags: c, arrays, random

I'm making a simple program that functions as a hot/cold guessing game with a randomly generated number (enter a guess, tells you higher or lower, repeats until correct number is guessed.) I've had some obstacles with random number generation, and the best solution I could create is generating an array of 1000 random numbers.

The first time playing through the game uses the first random number generated by the array, however, any time after the first game uses 4040 as the random number, regardless of the range of possible random numbers (should be 1-100 for the normal difficulty setting). I have tried to diagnose the problem in multiple ways, but I believe this problem is too difficult to solve with the very little experience I have with programming (I'm still in the process of taking my first programming course), so any help with identifying the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Relevant parts of the code:

```
int main()
{
    int randomArray[1000];
    int randomNum;
    int e=0; //element of each array
    int input, score;
    time_t t;
    char level='n', mode;

    //srand ( time(NULL) );
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    do
    {
        game();
    }
    while(level!='!');

    return 0;
}

void game()
{
    int randomArray[1000];
    int randomNum;
    int input;
    char level;

    printf("Chose difficulty (? for help, ! to quit): \n");
    printf("Normal (N)\n");
    printf("Medium (M)\n");
    printf("Hard (H)\n");
    printf("Impossible (I)\n");
    scanf("%c", &level);

    if(level=='N' || level=='n')
    {
        randomNum=rngNormal();
    }
    if(level=='M' || level=='m')
    {
        randomNum=rngMedium();
    }
    if(level=='H' || level=='h')
    {
        randomNum=rngHard();
    }
    if(level=='I' || level=='i')
    {
        randomNum=rngImpossible();
    }
    if(level=='?')
    {
        printf("Normal: generates random number from 1-100\nMedium: generates random number from 1-500\n");
        printf("Hard generates random number from 1-1,000\nImpossible: generates random number from 1-32,767");
    }

    getche();
    system("cls");
    printf("RANDOM NUMBER: %d\n", randomNum);//added for testing purposes
    input=load();
    while(input!=randomNum)
    {
        compare(input, randomNum);
        input=load();
     }
     compare(input, randomNum);

    return 0;
}

int rngNormal()
{
    int randomArray[1000];
    int randomNum;
    time_t t;
    int e=0;

    //generates random array
    if(e==0)
    {
        for(int a=0; a<1000; a++)
        {
            randomArray[a]=rand()%100+1;
        }

        for(int x=0; x<1000; x++)//added for testing purposes
        {
            printf("%3d ", randomArray[x]);
        }
    }

    randomNum=randomArray[e];

    e++;

    return randomNum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have quite a lot of issues, I'll try to list a few:

1. `int randomArray[1000];` is defined multiple times every time you define it in a function you will create a local copy of the array - they are completly unrelated although they share the same name
2. you return a value from a `void` function `void game() ... return 0;`
3. `level` is not a global value - hence when you change it in `game` it will not effect the value checked in `main`
4. I cannot understand any of the logic behind the use of the `randomArray[1000];` - what is the point you can just generate a random number and guess it - why do you need to generate 1000 of them? you are not using them in any way - `e` is local so you return from the function `randomArray[0]` evey time - the rest are discarded at function end

I do suggest debugging, review local\global variables in C you seem to have a misunderstanding how these are implemented. I suggest bulding a simpler app without function to start with - it will be simpler to debug, after you understand the logic you can start exporting code sections to functions. hope this helps..

Comment: Suggest adding `-Wshadow` as a compiler option to your default compile string to warn when a variable is shadowed.

Answer (score 0):

You shadow `randomArray, randomNum, input, level` between `main()` and `game()`. Changing the value in one has no effect on the other. Make `-Wshadow` a standard option you use when compiling so the compiler will warn you of the problem (if you are using VS (e.g. `cl.exe`, then use `/Wall` or `/W3`). Don't shadow variables, pass them as parameters to your function and return a proper value (or pass a pointer to the *address of* your variables -- so any changes are visible back in the calling function)

`while(level!='!');` will *Always* test `TRUE` because the value is never changed from the point of initialization (e.g. `char level='n'`) in `main()`.

You are obviously compiling without warnings enabled (or you are choosing to ingore them). Always compile with at minimum `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` on gcc/clang, `/W3` on VS. Read and understand each warning and do not accept code until it compiles without warning (you can use `/wXXXX` on VS to disable the warnings that are not germane to your code, where `XXXX` is the code associated with the specific warning you wish to disable)

`scanf ("%c", ...)` will read a single character leaving all others (including the `'\n'` generated by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the input buffer. You must account for it and remove it before attempting to read again or `scanf ("%c", ....)` will happilly take the uread `'\n'` as your next input. A better way to do input is using `fgets` which will read and include the trailing `'\n'` in the buffer it fills, insuring you don't fall into the `scanf` pitfall of failing to account for it.

Don't use `getche()` to do input or to keep the terminal window open. The `conio.h` header file is 100% non-portable to anything other than windows. Use `getcahr()` instead. `cls` is dubious as well (for the same reason)

You haven't provided the definition of `load();` or `compare()`, so we cannot offer help there. You cannot return a value from `game()`. It is declared type `void` and returns nothing. Further, there is no need to `return` at all at the end of the function -- that happens automagically. If you need to return eariler in a `void` function, simply use the word `return;`.

`rngNormal()` has similar shadowing errors. Your filling of `randomArray[a]` with `for(int a=0; a<1000; a++)` does not effect `randomArray` in `main()` for the reasons above. You don't show a call to `rngNormal()` so there is no way to tell if you use the return properly.

All of these are basic coding errors. Take the time and figure out what values you need to pass to your funciton from `main()` and then create a proper *parameter list* for each function passing the values as required. Enable compiler warnings and do not accept code until it compiles without error.

If you need more help, edit your question, adding any updated code **Below** your original question and we are happy to help further.